# Drag and drop to desktop in LiveCode

Tags: drag-and-drop, livecode

I'm working on an IDE extension. One of the first things I need to be able to do is drag an icon from my new tool panel out to
the open space and create a stack when released.

This is the code I have so far. The problem is that, when I release the drag, it pops the mouse back to the start position of
the drag and creates there rather then at the end position. I suspect that is because I am not dragging onto a destination object
since I am trying to make a new stack. How can I get the release point when its not over a LiveCode object?

```
on mouseDown
   set the dragData["text"] to empty

end mouseDown


on dragStart
    set the dragImage to the id of the target
end dragStart

on dragEnd
   CreateNewDBStack("New Databse Stack", "Default.sdb")
end dragEnd

command CreateNewDBStack  pNewStackName, pDBname
      #create stack
   create stack pNewStackName
   put it into tTheNewStack
   set the loc of tTheNewStack to the mouseloc
   set the DBPath of tTheNewStack to pDBName
   #create DBscript on stack
   local tScript
   put "global gDBConnectionID"&cr into tScript
   put "command onPreOpenStack"&cr after tScript
   put "   library stack "&quote&"DatabaseLibrary.livecode"&quote&cr  after tScript
   put "   put the DBPath of me into tDBPath"&cr after tScript
   put "   put databaseConnect(tDBPath) into gDBConnectionID" &cr after tScript
   put "end onPreOpenStack" after tScript
   set the script of tTheNewStack to tScript
end CreateNewDBStack
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `the screenMouseLoc` instead of `the mouseLoc`.

```
   set the loc of tTheNewStack to the screenMouseLoc
```

The DB stack may jump to the new location, so creating the stack invisibly then setting the visible to true at the end of your script will avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're doing a real drag and drop, since you're not actually dragging an object from an app to another app (e.g. from your app to Finder or Windows Explorer). Therefore, you could use a different approach without drag and drop.

The following method creates a place holder stack. You could change the script to not delete the place holder stack and adjust its properties instead. I decided to delete the place holder stack and then run your script.

```
on mouseDown
     set the rect of the templateStack to 0,0,100,100
     set the decorations of the templateStack to "maximize,minimize,close"
     set the backgroundColor of the templateStack to gray
     set the blendLevel of the templateStack to 50
     set the vis of the templateStack to true
     set the name of the templateStack to "extPlace Holder"
     set the loc of the templateStack to globalloc(the mouseLoc)
     create stack
     reset the templateStack
     send "followMouse it" to me in 0 millisecs
end mouseDown

on followMouse theStack
     put the mouseLoc into myLoc
     if the mouse is down then
          set the loc of theStack to globalLoc(myLoc)
          send "followMouse theStack" to me in 20 millisecs
     end if
end followMouse

on mouseRelease
     put the mouseLoc into myLoc
     if there is a stack "extPlace Holder" then delete stack "extPlace Holder"
     createNewStack "New Database Stack","Default.sdb"
     /*
     if there is a stack "New Database Stack" then
          set the loc of stack "New Database Stack" to myLoc
     end if
     */
end mouseRelease

on mouseUp
     put the mouseLoc into myLoc
     if there is a stack "extPlace Holder" then delete stack "extPlace Holder"
end mouseUp

command createNewStack pNewStackName,pDBname
     put globalLoc(the mouseloc) into myLoc
     #create stack
     set the vis of the templateStack to false
     create stack pNewStackName
     put it into tTheNewStack
     set the loc of tTheNewStack to myLoc
     set the DBPath of tTheNewStack to pDBName
     #create DBscript on stack
     local tScript
     put "global gDBConnectionID"&cr into tScript
     put "command onPreOpenStack"&cr after tScript
     put "   library stack "&quote&"DatabaseLibrary.livecode"&quote&cr  after tScript
     put "   put the DBPath of me into tDBPath"&cr after tScript
     put "   put databaseConnect(tDBPath) into gDBConnectionID" &cr after tScript
     put "end onPreOpenStack" after tScript
     set the script of tTheNewStack to tScript
     show tTheNewStack
     reset the templateStack
end createNewStack
```

Comment: I just noticed Paul's answer. ScreenMouseLoc and globalloc(the moueLoc) give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code helps you to finish your extension.
What I'm doing is creating a stack which I put the image that I drag as a background. Something similar to what the LiveCode IDE does.

**Important** in the _deleteDragStack command find where CreateNewDBStack is called and pass it the parameters pNewStackName, pDBname.

```
local sDragStack
local sStackLoc

on mouseMove
   if the mouse is up then
      _deleteDragStack
      
   else if the mouse is down and there is not a sDragStack then
      local tTarget
      
      put the target into tTarget
      if word 1 of tTarget is "image" then
         set the destroyStack of templateStack to true
         set the windowShape of templateStack to (the id of tTarget)
         set the backgroundPattern of templateStack to (the id  of tTarget)
         set the blendLevel of templateStack to 100
         set the loc of templateStack to globalLoc(the mouseLoc)
         create stack
         put it into sDragStack
         reset templateStack
      end if
   else if there is sDragStack then
      
      put globalLoc( the mouseLoc) into sStackLoc
      set the loc of sDragStack to sStackLoc
      set the blendLevel of sDragStack to 25
   end if
   pass mouseMove
end mouseMove

on mouseUp
   if there is sDragStack then _deleteDragStack
end mouseUp

on mouseRelease
   if there is sDragStack then _deleteDragStack
end mouseRelease

private command _deleteDragStack
   if there is sDragStack then
      lock messages
      close sDragStack
      
      CreateNewDBStack "Untitled"&&(random(1000))---> pNewStackName, pDBname
      
      delete local sDragStack
      unlock messages
   end if
end _deleteDragStack

command CreateNewDBStack  pNewStackName, pDBname
   local tTheNewStack
   #create stack
   create stack pNewStackName
   put it into tTheNewStack
   set the loc of tTheNewStack to sStackLoc
   set the DBPath of tTheNewStack to pDBName
   
   #create DBscript on stack
   local tScript
   put "global gDBConnectionID"&cr into tScript
   put "command onPreOpenStack"&cr after tScript
   put "   library stack "&quote&"DatabaseLibrary.livecode"&quote&cr  after tScript
   put "   put the DBPath of me into tDBPath"&cr after tScript
   put "   put databaseConnect(tDBPath) into gDBConnectionID" &cr after tScript
   put "end onPreOpenStack" after tScript
   set the script of tTheNewStack to tScript
end CreateNewDBStack
```